# SPE - Cannot index into a null array

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am trying to pass an Item to a SPE Function as follows:

```
function ImportTask ($importTask, $taskItem) {

    $taskName = $taskItem.Name

    $importTask.ItemTitle = $taskItem.Fields["Item Title"].Value

}

$taskObj = New-Object MyNamespace.Task

$contextItem = Get-Item -Path "."

ImportTask($taskObj, $contextItem)
```

However, when executed, I get the following error:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:5 char:2
+     $importTask.ItemTitle = $taskItem.Fields["Item Title"].Value
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Any suggestions why I cannot retrieve the value?

Comment: so what are you trying to do ? assign a field value to $imporTask from $taskItem's field ?

Comment: I have created an object of type Task, then I am adding a value from the item field Item Title to it. I am doing more processing on this but I am having the above error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To distinguish positional parameters, Powershell uses spaces instead of commas. By changing your invocation to this, you will fix your problem:

```
ImportTask $taskObj $contextItem
```

By using a comma, you are sending an array into the first parameter, and not defining the second.

There are a couple of blog posts by Michael Sorens which detail this in great length:

- https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole--a-study-in-powershell-pipelines,-functions,-and-parameters/
- https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/a-plethora-of-powershell-pitfalls/